# Substitute the value of a variable in a weblogic command

Tags: python, wlst, substitution

There is a command

```
application = raw_input('Enter the application name you want to deploy\t\n')
connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://host:port')
deploy(appName='application', 
       path='/home/application.war', 
       targets='MS1', 
       upload='true')
startApplication(appName='application')
```

In the above, application is a value entered by the user, and that value should be substituted in the commands `deploy` and `startApplication` of `wlst`.

I tried using `%s % value` and `.format(value=value)`, but I couldn't substitute the value of application in the deploy command.

How do we do it ? Any Ideas ?

I am using python 2.3.4

Comment: Aside: why in the name of all that is Pythonic are you using Python 2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

You should not enclose `application` variable with quotes, as it will be treated as a string. This should work for you:

```
application = raw_input('Enter the application name you want to deploy\t\n')

connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://host:port')

deploy(appName=application,
       path='/home/%s.war' % application, 
       targets='MS1', 
       upload='true')

startApplication(appName=application)
```